# Does putting synchronous functions in an async function still block nodejs?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, async-await, require

For example, `require` is synchronous.

If I put require in an async function and call that async function, does it block nodejs?

Comment: Async is *cooperative* multitasking; if you can't await it (or pass a callback), it's blocking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I put require in an async function and call that async function, does it block nodejs?

Yes, it does.  If the module you are using `require()` to load is not already cached, then it will block the interpreter to load the module from disk using synchronous file I/O.  The fact that it's in an `async` function doesn't affect anything in this regard.

`async` functions don't change blocking, synchronous operations in any way.  They provide automatic exception handling and allow the use of `await` and always return a promise.  They have no magic powers to affect synchronous operations within the function.

FYI, in nearly all cases, modules you will need in your code should be loaded at module initialization.  They can then be referenced later from other code without blocking the interpreter to load them.

Comment: What about import()? Will that also block io and the interpreter?

Comment: @DarrenRahnemoon - Yes, `import` is also synchronous and it blocks.  Both `import` and `require()` in node.js are primarily designed for startup code when it would really, really, really complicate things if it was asynchronous.

Comment: I've been looking for this explanation for a while now. Thank you for clarifying. I have a rmSync call in an async function which I suspected was blocking the nodejs thread, and according to you it does :)

Answer (score 0):

It will still block. This is true for whichever blocking code you would wrap in an `async` function. Also realise that using an `async` function is not useful unless you also use `await` in it.

You could for instance write the `async` function as follows:

```
async function work() {
    await null;
    synchronous_task();
}

work();
console.log("called work");
```

Here the call to `work` will return immediately, because of the `await`, but as soon as the code following that call has completed (until the call stack is empty), the execution will continue with what follows the `await null`, and will still block until that synchronous code has finished executing.